# Underscore doesn't recognize definitely typed properties

Tags: typescript, underscore.js, angular5

Why underscore can't show model's properties in intallisanse.

```js
this.accountService.getAll().subscribe(
  (accounts : Account[])  => {

    accounts.forEach(g => g.email) // standart forEach revails all my typed properies
    let account = _.each(accounts, (r) => r....??); // here is nothing, also _.find method and etc

    return true;
  },
  (e) => this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Forgot Password', e.error.message))
```

Comment: Do you have the types for underscore installed ? `npm install @types/underscore`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, yes, "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.8",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.8",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3",

Comment: All seems to work fine for me, with typescript:  2.5.3 and @types/underscore: 1.8.8